# Gravitational non-linearities and Dark Matter/Energy

Tags: gravity, dark-matter, dark-energy, non-linear-systems, strong-force

I had read Significance of Gravitational Nonlinearities on the Dynamics of Disk Galaxies (https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.00095), was wondering

Is there good reason to think that gravitational non-linearities arising from the known laws of nature can't explain all the observational evidence attributed to dark matter and energy?

As I understand it, this approach treats gravitational self-interaction differently than conventional general-relativity does, which treats it only indirectly, instead the authors take inspiration from QCD which to me seems good since gravity and the strong force are the first forces to differentiate in our universe so they should have some similarities; is this wrong?

Comment: Suggestion to the post (v2): Try to focus on/ask only 1 subquestion.

Comment: This paper presents an intriguing alternative to dark matter, but I don't think it has anything to do with dark energy.

Comment: The author has other papers that explain dark energy effects arising because gravitons diverted to creating dark matter phenomena aren't leaving the galaxy and hence weakening the gravitational force between galaxies. (https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.02481)